# Rounding values prior to using subtotal function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I asked this question a couple of week back, however deleted it after going down a different track. It has now come up again.

I use the following formula to total the values in the DK range, based on if the value in the associated EC column equals "EE", which works perfectly.

I also want to keep this type of formula so that I can filter on other columns and it will automatically alter the total based on what is being displayed.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET($DK$18,ROW($DK$18:$DK$4102)-ROW($DK$18),,1)),--($EC$18:$EC$4102 = "EE"))
```

Below is a snippet from the spreadsheet

[image]

**The Question**

I would like to expand this formula to round the values in the DK range to 2 decimal places before it gets subtotalled.

Is this possible and if so how?

Comment: Excel has a `ROUND` function, which you might be able to use if you can refactor your equation.

Comment: I'm open to suggestion, do you have any ideas? I am hoping to be able to keep the filtering recalcuation.

Comment: `ROUND` appears to only work on single cells, unless you want to write VBA code.  You can do away with the array formulas.

Comment: Not sure on the single cells as you can do an array formula like [=Sum(Round(DK189:DK200, 2))}

Comment: As far as VBA I use it to create the report above, did you mean creating a custom function that can be used in a formula?

Comment: Love to know why I'm marked down, without some active (constructive) criticism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to set the [ROUND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ROUND-function-C018C5D8-40FB-4053-90B1-B3E7F61A213C) operation in the wrong place. Each cycle of the [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff) function is acting on a single digit from the [SUBTOTAL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBTOTAL-function-e27c301c-be9a-458b-9d12-b9a2ce3c62af) function; it only matters whether SUBTOTAL believes it to be hidden or not. That is what needs to be ROUNDed, not the range in the [OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592) function. The range in the OFFSET function has been converted to an incremental set of numbers with the [ROW](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/ROW-function-3A63B74A-C4D0-4093-B49A-E76EB49A6D8D) function (e.g. {0, 1, 2, ... 4082, 4083, 4084}).

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ROUND(SUBTOTAL(9, OFFSET($DK$18, ROW($DK$18:$DK$4102)-ROW($DK$18), 0, 1, 1)), 2), --($EC$18:$EC$4102 = "EE"))
```

I'm not going to retype your image's data so no pretty pictures. You might also want to look into the more recent [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) as a substitute for SUBTOTAL (xl2010+).